# How can i only count a record once if there are duplicates

Tags: sql-server-2008

### Table

```
|  Word    |  ID  | 
-------------------
|computer  |   1  |
|computer  |   1  |
|computer  |   1  |
|computer  |   2  |
|Printer   |   1  |
|Printer   |   2  |
```

### Desired Results

```
|  Word    |  WordCount | 
-------------------------
|computer  |   2        |
|Printer   |   2        |
```

A word can be in the table with the same ID multiple times. I can get the number of times each word occurs:

```
select 
  distinct(word),count(word) as WordCount
from
  table1 
group by  word
```

But I don't know how to only count the record once if the Word and ID columns are the same.

This is the closest I have gotten:

```
select distinct(word), id from table1
```

Which almost gives me what i want, it returns one word per ID but I need the Count for each word.

So my question is how can I get a count of every word while excluding rows that have the same Word and ID, after the first one is counted.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have duplicate Word / Id combinations in the first place. (Maybe there is a genuine need for this type of data model but I'm struggling to imagine a scenario where it would be desired). I'd be more concerned with normalising the data so a standard `select word, count(*)` statement will work.

Comment: It's unclear what is the primary key of the table here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Sub Select like this:

```
select word, count(word) as WordCount FROM (
select 
  word
from
  table1
group by word, id
) t1 group by word
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use DISTINCT within COUNT:

```
select 
distinct(word),count(distinct word) as WordCount
from
table1 
group by  word
```

Refer to SQL COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) syntax in http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp.

Comment: This counts each Word once, the results I get from this query are a count of 1 for each word. If there is a Word with different ID's the count should be 2, records with the same Word and ID should only be counted once.

Comment: what is pk here then?